# How can i avoid game freezes caused by while loop?

Tags: loops, while-loop, unity-game-engine, freeze

I am working on RRT path finding system. Basically, it generates random points to find a path. I finished it successfully but am faced with a serious problem. While generating these points I am using a `while` statement and it takes around 10,000 - 15,000 loop iterations. As you might guess, it freezes the game for 1-2 sec. I thought to use `yield` for my `while` statement but if I am right, when I use that, my `while` loop will work one time per frame. Then if I have 60 fps, it will take 250 seconds to finish this `while` loop. This is impossible to ignore. So my question is: how can I finish this while loop without any game freezes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chanibal stated, threading is still possible. I'm certainly not touting this the best way to accomplish what you are after, but since you didn't seem too keen on Sorin's answer, I thought I'd mention that you can use a yield statement still.

You don't have to yield after a single loop iteration. One example:

```
int i = 0;
while (yourCondition)
{
    if (++i % 100 == 0)
        yield return null;
}
```

This yields after every 100 iterations. There are a myriad of other ways to conditionally yield, you just need to decide what best fits your situation.

Comment: Well this may work. Very simple and good solution, i dont know how we didnt think that. Thnx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here but none that are very simple:

1. Use a faster algorithm. Random doesn't sound very efficient.
2. Precompute stuff. For example you could
   figure out common or choke points then precompute paths between
   these    points. Then you only have to find out the path to one of
   those    points and it should run faster.
3. Don't run the algorithm every frame. You could spawn a new thread. Let the while run there but keep the rest of the game running. This is more complicated since you'll need to deal with synchronization issues.

Comment: Well i cant use faster algorithm because I am in probation and thats what my boss wants. RRT is new kind of path finding system and they want to try that. Dijkstra or A* would work better maybe but this also allows me to find my way in 3D too. Anyway i tought about threading too but as i know multi-thread is not possible in unity. I am reading something about that atm. If you have any link to share, it would be really nice.

Comment: Threading is possible in unity. You cannot modify or read most of game data, but if you copy what is needed in the main thread and work on the copy it'll be OK.